# Unable to type dollar symbol after installing Gnome 3.10 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome, 14.04, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I recently installed the Gnome 3.10 which is compatible with Ubuntu 14.04. I am not sure if that is what caused this, but I am unable to type the dollar symbol (Shift + 4) anywhere. I have used multiple keyboards and the problem persists. So it's not a hardware issue. I have only Ubuntu installed, so I cannot check it by logging into a different OS.

Any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: What input source (keyboard layout) do you use?

Comment: English (US) is what I used. I tried other English (US) layouts as well.